# replace trademark symbol (™) when alone

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to remove trademark symbol (™) but only in the case it's not followed by any other symbol for instance I might have â€™ which is a bad encoding of quotation mark (')  so I don't want to remove trademark symbol (™) and hence broking the pattern that i'm using to replace xx™ with quotation mark.

```
dict = {};

chars = {
    '\xe2\x84\xa2': '', # ™
    '\xe2\x80\x99': "'", # â€™
        }

def stats_change(char, number):
  if dict.has_key(char):
    dict[char] = dict[char]+number
  else:
    dict[char] = number # Add new entry

def replace_chars(match):
  char = match.group(0)
  stats_change(char,1)

  return chars[char]

i, nmatches = re.subn("(\\" + '|\\'.join(chars.keys()) + ")", replace_chars, i)
count_matches += nmatches
```

Input: `foo™ oof`
Output: `foo oof`

Input: `oâ€™f oof`
Output: `o'f oof`

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Perform your "fix encoding problem" before running the regex to remove TM and the problem will not happen. Otherwise you will need to check for every possible way TM could end up in an encoding error which may make the regex long.

Comment: Probably you need `re.sub(r'™\b|\b™', '', s)`

Comment: You might find ftfy useful: https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/